# Apollo Server gql usage recommendation

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server

I've been implementing a GraphQL server for the first time. While reading the documentation, I found the recommendation to use gql with typeDefs (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/migration-two-dot#existing-schema). I know the purpose of gql but I don't understand why its needed with Apollo Server if the constructor parses typeDefs internally. My code works with and without it.

Why is gql recommended to be used?

---

Update v1

Due to the combination of using gql with tools like eslint, I immediately noticed the benefits described in the answer. Without gql, available tools aren't smart enough to differentiate between a template string and graphql.

Comment: Guess this is too broad or will lead to opinionated answers

Comment: Why is too broad? I don't even know one reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really just a design choice on the part of the Apollo team. `graphql-tools`, which is what `apollo-server` uses under the hood, supports a number of types for the `typeDefs` parameter, including a function:

```
export type ITypeDefinitions = ITypedef | ITypedef[];
export type ITypedef = (() => ITypedef[]) | string | DocumentNode;
```

Because the constructor `ApolloServer` effectively just passes your `typeDefs` to `graphql-tools`' `makeExecutableSchema`, you can get away with passing in your schema's type definitions as a string or a function and it will still work. At least in JavaScript. The TypeScript definitions actually explicitly specify `DocumentNode` as the type, so if you were using TypeScript, it'd be a no-go.

Why does `apollo-server` explicitly require you to pass in a `DocumentNode` (which is what `graphql-tag` returns)? As one of the Apollo devs points out in [this PR](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/pull/2178):

> Supporting non-tagged-template-literals strings as typeDefs... makes it possible to define a document without a gql tag, which might be tempting, but it's worth reminding ourselves that there's some value to that tag since it makes it easier to do static analysis, automatic detection of string manipulation/variable interpolation (which is often an anti-pattern) and provides more ubiquitous editor syntax highlighting support.

If you're passing in `typeDefs`, you ***should*** make sure you're passing them in as a `DocumentNode`, and the easiest way to do is using the `gql` tag. Passing in one of the other types may appear to work, but the documentation and the type definitions make it clear you shouldn't do that. Keep in mind that Apollo Server could always introduce logic in future releases that results in unexpected behavior when the wrong type is passed in, if such code doesn't already exist.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea such features were available with the usage of gql. Typescript is something I plan on using in the future so I'll start using it right away.